# Eclipse and Java- need to install the legacy SE 6 runtime

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to get Eclipse to run. Here's the info on my java version-

[image: java version info]

And when I try to run Eclipse, this is what I get-

[image: Eclipse error]

Does this mean I have to uninstall my current version of Java and download the legacy SE 6? I'd rather not do that, is there a simpler way to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to download and install newer version of eclipse. which one are you opening?

Comment: I'm using the release 4.3.0. Does that help? What is the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eclipse version seems very old to require Java 6.

The latest version currently available is [Oxygen](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen).
You can download from their official website. Downloading legacy java 6 is not a recommended idea.

Comment: Hey thanks! I have downloaded Oxygen, it's running fine now!

Comment: If it helped consider accepting it and closing as it may help someone with a similar problem